How to create Java extension for Burp Suite Pro using IntelliJ?
I'm trying to create my first extension for Portswigger Burp Suite Professional using IntelliJ... and making zero progress because my generated .jar file gets rejected when I try loading it into Burp.
Update:
I finally came to my senses & decided to ditch Gradle. I created a new Maven-based Java project, re-created the two classes, built the Jar using Maven's "Package" archetype, and had it working in Burp within ~10 minutes.
I'm going to leave the question open for a few days, just in case there's someone out there who actually knows how to make this work via Gradle. I'd dearly love to learn. My /src directory is littered with the corpses of abandoned Gradle-based Java projects that ultimately ended up having to be re-created as Maven projects because I just couldn't get a working .Jar file using Gradle and IntelliJ's byzantine artifact system.
anyway, back to the original post...
java.lang.Exception: Extension class is not a recognized type
    at burp.Zlsy.ZR(Unknown Source)
    at burp.Zlsy.ZZ(Unknown Source)
    at burp.Zfr3.ZR(Unknown Source)
    at burp.Zbg2.Zl(Unknown Source)
    at burp.Zxfq.lambda$panelLoaded$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

I suspect the problem's root might lie with Gradle or the generated .jar file... but I can't say for sure.
Details:

SDK: graalvm-ce-17
Version: IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.1 (Community Edition)
Platform: Macbook Pro (M3 Max), Sonoma 14.6.1
Burp Version: Burp Suite Professional, v2024.7.5

The generated  .jar file's Manifest.MF file contains only a single line:
Manifest-Version: 1.0

(directory listing of the .jar file's contents is at the very end)
SessionSender.java (the main extension clas)

import burp.api.montoya.BurpExtension;
import burp.api.montoya.MontoyaApi;
import burp.api.montoya.logging.Logging;

public class SessionSender implements BurpExtension {
    MontoyaApi api;
    Logging log;
    Sender sender = new Sender(log);
    @Override
    public void initialize(MontoyaApi montoyaApi) {
        api = montoyaApi;
        log = api.logging();
        api.extension().setName("SessionSender");
        log.logToOutput("SessionSender is outputting a message!");
        api.http().registerHttpHandler(sender);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Foo!");
    }
}

Sender.java:
package pantherkitty.burp.sessionsender;

import burp.api.montoya.http.handler.*;
import burp.api.montoya.logging.Logging;

public class Sender implements HttpHandler {
    Logging log;
    public Sender(Logging logging) {
        this.log = logging;
        log.logToOutput("Created SessionSender.Sender");
    }
    @Override
    public RequestToBeSentAction handleHttpRequestToBeSent(HttpRequestToBeSent httpRequestToBeSent) {
        log.logToOutput("Something called SessionSender.Sender.RequestToBeSentAction()");
        return RequestToBeSentAction.continueWith(httpRequestToBeSent);
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseReceivedAction handleHttpResponseReceived(HttpResponseReceived httpResponseReceived) {
        log.logToOutput("Something called SessionSender.Sender.handleHttpResponseReceived");
        return ResponseReceivedAction.continueWith(httpResponseReceived);
    }
}


build.gradle:
plugins {
    // added after reading https://bishopfox.com/blog/power-pen-tests-with-montoya-api
    // to try and use Shadow to build the jar
    id 'com.gradleup.shadow' version '8.3.0'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'pantherkitty.burp.sessionsender'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    implementation 'net.portswigger.burp.extensions:montoya-api:+'
}

// added after reading tutorial at 
// https://security.humanativaspa.it/extending-burp-suite-for-fun-and-profit-the-montoya-way-part-1/
jar {
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


Directory listing of .jar file:
% ls -lR
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 jeff  staff   96 Sep  3 21:59 META-INF
drwxr-xr-x  4 jeff  staff  128 Sep  3 22:01 burp
drwxr-xr-x  4 jeff  staff  128 Sep  3 22:01 pantherkitty

./META-INF:
total 8
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jeff  staff  25 Sep  3 21:59 MANIFEST.MF

./burp:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  4 jeff  staff  128 Sep  3 22:01 api

./burp/api:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  26 jeff  staff  832 Jul 31 13:25 montoya

./burp/api/montoya:
total 16
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   180 Jul 31 13:25 BurpExtension.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1255 Jul 31 13:25 MontoyaApi.class
drwxr-xr-x   6 jeff  staff   192 Jul 31 13:25 burpsuite
drwxr-xr-x  18 jeff  staff   576 Jul 31 13:25 collaborator
drwxr-xr-x   3 jeff  staff    96 Jul 31 13:25 comparer
drwxr-xr-x  13 jeff  staff   416 Jul 31 13:25 core
drwxr-xr-x   3 jeff  staff    96 Jul 31 13:25 decoder
drwxr-xr-x   4 jeff  staff   128 Jul 31 13:25 extension
drwxr-xr-x  11 jeff  staff   352 Jul 31 13:25 http
drwxr-xr-x   4 jeff  staff   128 Jul 31 13:25 internal
drwxr-xr-x  14 jeff  staff   448 Jul 31 13:25 intruder
drwxr-xr-x   4 jeff  staff   128 Jul 31 13:25 logger
drwxr-xr-x   3 jeff  staff    96 Jul 31 13:25 logging
drwxr-xr-x   3 jeff  staff    96 Jul 31 13:25 organizer
drwxr-xr-x   6 jeff  staff   192 Jul 31 13:25 persistence
drwxr-xr-x   3 jeff  staff    96 Jul 31 13:25 project
drwxr-xr-x  11 jeff  staff   352 Jul 31 13:25 proxy
drwxr-xr-x   3 jeff  staff    96 Jul 31 13:25 repeater
drwxr-xr-x  16 jeff  staff   512 Jul 31 13:25 scanner
drwxr-xr-x   5 jeff  staff   160 Jul 31 13:25 scope
drwxr-xr-x   5 jeff  staff   160 Jul 31 13:25 sitemap
drwxr-xr-x   9 jeff  staff   288 Jul 31 13:25 ui
drwxr-xr-x  19 jeff  staff   608 Jul 31 13:25 utilities
drwxr-xr-x  14 jeff  staff   448 Jul 31 13:25 websocket

./burp/api/montoya/burpsuite:
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   658 Jul 31 13:25 BurpSuite.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1133 Jul 31 13:25 ShutdownOptions.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1485 Jul 31 13:25 TaskExecutionEngine$TaskExecutionEngineState.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   500 Jul 31 13:25 TaskExecutionEngine.class

./burp/api/montoya/collaborator:
total 128
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   432 Jul 31 13:25 Collaborator.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   965 Jul 31 13:25 CollaboratorClient.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   467 Jul 31 13:25 CollaboratorPayload.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   295 Jul 31 13:25 CollaboratorPayloadGenerator.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   221 Jul 31 13:25 CollaboratorServer.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   254 Jul 31 13:25 DnsDetails.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1956 Jul 31 13:25 DnsQueryType.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   275 Jul 31 13:25 HttpDetails.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   795 Jul 31 13:25 Interaction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   792 Jul 31 13:25 InteractionFilter.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   179 Jul 31 13:25 InteractionId.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1245 Jul 31 13:25 InteractionType.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1149 Jul 31 13:25 PayloadOption.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   578 Jul 31 13:25 SecretKey.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   247 Jul 31 13:25 SmtpDetails.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1175 Jul 31 13:25 SmtpProtocol.class

./burp/api/montoya/comparer:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  188 Jul 31 13:25 Comparer.class

./burp/api/montoya/core:
total 88
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1314 Jul 31 13:25 Annotations.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1526 Jul 31 13:25 BurpSuiteEdition.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  2002 Jul 31 13:25 ByteArray.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  2186 Jul 31 13:25 HighlightColor.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   737 Jul 31 13:25 Marker.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   559 Jul 31 13:25 Range.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   183 Jul 31 13:25 Registration.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   181 Jul 31 13:25 Task.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   239 Jul 31 13:25 ToolSource.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  2232 Jul 31 13:25 ToolType.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   466 Jul 31 13:25 Version.class

./burp/api/montoya/decoder:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  183 Jul 31 13:25 Decoder.class

./burp/api/montoya/extension:
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  386 Jul 31 13:25 Extension.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  192 Jul 31 13:25 ExtensionUnloadingHandler.class

./burp/api/montoya/http:
total 48
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1896 Jul 31 13:25 Http.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1218 Jul 31 13:25 HttpMode.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1127 Jul 31 13:25 HttpProtocol.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   958 Jul 31 13:25 HttpService.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1261 Jul 31 13:25 RedirectionMode.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   784 Jul 31 13:25 RequestOptions.class
drwxr-xr-x  10 jeff  staff   320 Jul 31 13:25 handler
drwxr-xr-x  12 jeff  staff   384 Jul 31 13:25 message
drwxr-xr-x   6 jeff  staff   192 Jul 31 13:25 sessions

./burp/api/montoya/http/handler:
total 64
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   426 Jul 31 13:25 HttpHandler.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  3985 Jul 31 13:25 HttpRequestToBeSent.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  3100 Jul 31 13:25 HttpResponseReceived.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1134 Jul 31 13:25 RequestAction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1353 Jul 31 13:25 RequestToBeSentAction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1141 Jul 31 13:25 ResponseAction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1371 Jul 31 13:25 ResponseReceivedAction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   312 Jul 31 13:25 TimingData.class

./burp/api/montoya/http/message:
total 56
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1438 Jul 31 13:25 ContentType.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   327 Jul 31 13:25 Cookie.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   779 Jul 31 13:25 HttpHeader.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   903 Jul 31 13:25 HttpMessage.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  2618 Jul 31 13:25 HttpRequestResponse.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  3073 Jul 31 13:25 MimeType.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1930 Jul 31 13:25 StatusCodeClass.class
drwxr-xr-x  5 jeff  staff   160 Jul 31 13:25 params
drwxr-xr-x  5 jeff  staff   160 Jul 31 13:25 requests
drwxr-xr-x  4 jeff  staff   128 Jul 31 13:25 responses

./burp/api/montoya/http/message/params:
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1237 Jul 31 13:25 HttpParameter.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1533 Jul 31 13:25 HttpParameterType.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   423 Jul 31 13:25 ParsedHttpParameter.class

./burp/api/montoya/http/message/requests:
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  6275 Jul 31 13:25 HttpRequest.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1228 Jul 31 13:25 HttpTransformation.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   452 Jul 31 13:25 MalformedRequestException.class

./burp/api/montoya/http/message/responses:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  3808 Jul 31 13:25 HttpResponse.class
drwxr-xr-x  7 jeff  staff   224 Jul 31 13:25 analysis

./burp/api/montoya/http/message/responses/analysis:
total 40
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   254 Jul 31 13:25 Attribute.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  3134 Jul 31 13:25 AttributeType.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   217 Jul 31 13:25 KeywordCount.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   401 Jul 31 13:25 ResponseKeywordsAnalyzer.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   455 Jul 31 13:25 ResponseVariationsAnalyzer.class

./burp/api/montoya/http/sessions:
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1004 Jul 31 13:25 ActionResult.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   373 Jul 31 13:25 CookieJar.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   324 Jul 31 13:25 SessionHandlingAction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   446 Jul 31 13:25 SessionHandlingActionData.class

./burp/api/montoya/internal:
total 40
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  15964 Jul 31 13:25 MontoyaObjectFactory.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff    470 Jul 31 13:25 ObjectFactoryLocator.class

./burp/api/montoya/intruder:
total 96
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   352 Jul 31 13:25 AttackConfiguration.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   907 Jul 31 13:25 GeneratedPayload.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  2062 Jul 31 13:25 HttpRequestTemplate.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1389 Jul 31 13:25 HttpRequestTemplateGenerationOptions.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   756 Jul 31 13:25 Intruder.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   209 Jul 31 13:25 IntruderInsertionPoint.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   298 Jul 31 13:25 PayloadData.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   267 Jul 31 13:25 PayloadGenerator.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   330 Jul 31 13:25 PayloadGeneratorProvider.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1242 Jul 31 13:25 PayloadProcessingAction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1160 Jul 31 13:25 PayloadProcessingResult.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   304 Jul 31 13:25 PayloadProcessor.class

./burp/api/montoya/logger:
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  808 Jul 31 13:25 LoggerCaptureHttpRequestResponse.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  823 Jul 31 13:25 LoggerHttpRequestResponse.class

./burp/api/montoya/logging:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  542 Jul 31 13:25 Logging.class

./burp/api/montoya/organizer:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  275 Jul 31 13:25 Organizer.class

./burp/api/montoya/persistence:
total 40
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  2038 Jul 31 13:25 PersistedList.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  5971 Jul 31 13:25 PersistedObject.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   276 Jul 31 13:25 Persistence.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1178 Jul 31 13:25 Preferences.class

./burp/api/montoya/project:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  158 Jul 31 13:25 Project.class

./burp/api/montoya/proxy:
total 56
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1318 Jul 31 13:25 MessageReceivedAction.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1199 Jul 31 13:25 MessageToBeSentAction.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1244 Jul 31 13:25 Proxy.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   213 Jul 31 13:25 ProxyHistoryFilter.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1299 Jul 31 13:25 ProxyHttpRequestResponse.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   228 Jul 31 13:25 ProxyWebSocketHistoryFilter.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   668 Jul 31 13:25 ProxyWebSocketMessage.class
drwxr-xr-x  11 jeff  staff   352 Jul 31 13:25 http
drwxr-xr-x  12 jeff  staff   384 Jul 31 13:25 websocket

./burp/api/montoya/proxy/http:
total 72
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   314 Jul 31 13:25 InterceptedHttpMessage.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  4091 Jul 31 13:25 InterceptedRequest.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  3224 Jul 31 13:25 InterceptedResponse.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   429 Jul 31 13:25 ProxyRequestHandler.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  2139 Jul 31 13:25 ProxyRequestReceivedAction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1690 Jul 31 13:25 ProxyRequestToBeSentAction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   437 Jul 31 13:25 ProxyResponseHandler.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  2161 Jul 31 13:25 ProxyResponseReceivedAction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1710 Jul 31 13:25 ProxyResponseToBeSentAction.class

./burp/api/montoya/proxy/websocket:
total 80
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1639 Jul 31 13:25 BinaryMessageReceivedAction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1230 Jul 31 13:25 BinaryMessageToBeSentAction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   391 Jul 31 13:25 InterceptedBinaryMessage.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   370 Jul 31 13:25 InterceptedTextMessage.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   979 Jul 31 13:25 ProxyMessageHandler.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   490 Jul 31 13:25 ProxyWebSocket.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   319 Jul 31 13:25 ProxyWebSocketCreation.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   269 Jul 31 13:25 ProxyWebSocketCreationHandler.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1570 Jul 31 13:25 TextMessageReceivedAction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1165 Jul 31 13:25 TextMessageToBeSentAction.class

./burp/api/montoya/repeater:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  290 Jul 31 13:25 Repeater.class

./burp/api/montoya/scanner:
total 96
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   633 Jul 31 13:25 AuditConfiguration.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1110 Jul 31 13:25 AuditResult.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1280 Jul 31 13:25 BuiltInAuditConfiguration.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1262 Jul 31 13:25 ConsolidationAction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   277 Jul 31 13:25 Crawl.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   293 Jul 31 13:25 CrawlAndAudit.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   652 Jul 31 13:25 CrawlConfiguration.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1143 Jul 31 13:25 ReportFormat.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   603 Jul 31 13:25 ScanCheck.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   140 Jul 31 13:25 ScanConfiguration.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   276 Jul 31 13:25 ScanTask.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1045 Jul 31 13:25 Scanner.class
drwxr-xr-x  6 jeff  staff   192 Jul 31 13:25 audit
drwxr-xr-x  5 jeff  staff   160 Jul 31 13:25 bchecks

./burp/api/montoya/scanner/audit:
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  804 Jul 31 13:25 Audit.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  232 Jul 31 13:25 AuditIssueHandler.class
drwxr-xr-x  5 jeff  staff  160 Jul 31 13:25 insertionpoint
drwxr-xr-x  6 jeff  staff  192 Jul 31 13:25 issues

./burp/api/montoya/scanner/audit/insertionpoint:
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1568 Jul 31 13:25 AuditInsertionPoint.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   447 Jul 31 13:25 AuditInsertionPointProvider.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  2276 Jul 31 13:25 AuditInsertionPointType.class

./burp/api/montoya/scanner/audit/issues:
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  2948 Jul 31 13:25 AuditIssue.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1337 Jul 31 13:25 AuditIssueConfidence.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   967 Jul 31 13:25 AuditIssueDefinition.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1435 Jul 31 13:25 AuditIssueSeverity.class

./burp/api/montoya/scanner/bchecks:
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1423 Jul 31 13:25 BCheckImportResult$Status.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   465 Jul 31 13:25 BCheckImportResult.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   312 Jul 31 13:25 BChecks.class

./burp/api/montoya/scope:
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  355 Jul 31 13:25 Scope.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  126 Jul 31 13:25 ScopeChange.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  205 Jul 31 13:25 ScopeChangeHandler.class

./burp/api/montoya/sitemap:
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  815 Jul 31 13:25 SiteMap.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  599 Jul 31 13:25 SiteMapFilter.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  165 Jul 31 13:25 SiteMapNode.class

./burp/api/montoya/ui:
total 24
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1002 Jul 31 13:25 Selection.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1066 Jul 31 13:25 Theme.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1653 Jul 31 13:25 UserInterface.class
drwxr-xr-x  13 jeff  staff   416 Jul 31 13:25 contextmenu
drwxr-xr-x   9 jeff  staff   288 Jul 31 13:25 editor
drwxr-xr-x   6 jeff  staff   192 Jul 31 13:25 menu
drwxr-xr-x   3 jeff  staff    96 Jul 31 13:25 swing

./burp/api/montoya/ui/contextmenu:
total 88
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   454 Jul 31 13:25 AuditIssueContextMenuEvent.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   194 Jul 31 13:25 ComponentEvent.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   800 Jul 31 13:25 ContextMenuEvent.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1326 Jul 31 13:25 ContextMenuItemsProvider.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   295 Jul 31 13:25 InvocationSource.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  2368 Jul 31 13:25 InvocationType.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1574 Jul 31 13:25 MessageEditorHttpRequestResponse$SelectionContext.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   854 Jul 31 13:25 MessageEditorHttpRequestResponse.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   554 Jul 31 13:25 WebSocketContextMenuEvent.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   635 Jul 31 13:25 WebSocketEditorEvent.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   408 Jul 31 13:25 WebSocketMessage.class

./burp/api/montoya/ui/editor:
total 48
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   401 Jul 31 13:25 Editor.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1250 Jul 31 13:25 EditorOptions.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   621 Jul 31 13:25 HttpRequestEditor.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   629 Jul 31 13:25 HttpResponseEditor.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   598 Jul 31 13:25 RawEditor.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   595 Jul 31 13:25 WebSocketMessageEditor.class
drwxr-xr-x  11 jeff  staff   352 Jul 31 13:25 extension

./burp/api/montoya/ui/editor/extension:
total 72
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   295 Jul 31 13:25 EditorCreationContext.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1210 Jul 31 13:25 EditorMode.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   504 Jul 31 13:25 ExtensionProvidedEditor.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   672 Jul 31 13:25 ExtensionProvidedHttpRequestEditor.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   677 Jul 31 13:25 ExtensionProvidedHttpResponseEditor.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   585 Jul 31 13:25 ExtensionProvidedWebSocketMessageEditor.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   341 Jul 31 13:25 HttpRequestEditorProvider.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   345 Jul 31 13:25 HttpResponseEditorProvider.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   352 Jul 31 13:25 WebSocketMessageEditorProvider.class

./burp/api/montoya/ui/menu:
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  711 Jul 31 13:25 BasicMenuItem.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  928 Jul 31 13:25 Menu.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  283 Jul 31 13:25 MenuBar.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  560 Jul 31 13:25 MenuItem.class

./burp/api/montoya/ui/swing:
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  327 Jul 31 13:25 SwingUtils.class

./burp/api/montoya/utilities:
total 136
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1167 Jul 31 13:25 Base64DecodingOptions.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1224 Jul 31 13:25 Base64EncodingOptions.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   870 Jul 31 13:25 Base64Utils.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   437 Jul 31 13:25 ByteUtils.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1233 Jul 31 13:25 CompressionType.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   295 Jul 31 13:25 CompressionUtils.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   270 Jul 31 13:25 CryptoUtils.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  6085 Jul 31 13:25 DigestAlgorithm.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  1304 Jul 31 13:25 HtmlEncoding.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   291 Jul 31 13:25 HtmlUtils.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   752 Jul 31 13:25 NumberUtils.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff  3312 Jul 31 13:25 RandomUtils$CharacterSet.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   578 Jul 31 13:25 RandomUtils.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   239 Jul 31 13:25 StringUtils.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   286 Jul 31 13:25 URLUtils.class
-rw-r--r--   1 jeff  staff   793 Jul 31 13:25 Utilities.class
drwxr-xr-x  12 jeff  staff   384 Jul 31 13:25 json

./burp/api/montoya/utilities/json:
total 80
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1973 Jul 31 13:25 JsonArrayNode.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   771 Jul 31 13:25 JsonBooleanNode.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   402 Jul 31 13:25 JsonException.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1063 Jul 31 13:25 JsonNode.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   550 Jul 31 13:25 JsonNullNode.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1067 Jul 31 13:25 JsonNumberNode.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  2166 Jul 31 13:25 JsonObjectNode.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   436 Jul 31 13:25 JsonParseException.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   799 Jul 31 13:25 JsonStringNode.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   635 Jul 31 13:25 JsonUtils.class

./burp/api/montoya/websocket:
total 88
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   253 Jul 31 13:25 BinaryMessage.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1430 Jul 31 13:25 BinaryMessageAction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1159 Jul 31 13:25 Direction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1167 Jul 31 13:25 MessageAction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   552 Jul 31 13:25 MessageHandler.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   234 Jul 31 13:25 TextMessage.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1344 Jul 31 13:25 TextMessageAction.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   382 Jul 31 13:25 WebSocket.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   345 Jul 31 13:25 WebSocketCreated.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   238 Jul 31 13:25 WebSocketCreatedHandler.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   542 Jul 31 13:25 WebSockets.class
drwxr-xr-x  6 jeff  staff   192 Jul 31 13:25 extension

./burp/api/montoya/websocket/extension:
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   438 Jul 31 13:25 ExtensionWebSocket.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   527 Jul 31 13:25 ExtensionWebSocketCreation.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1748 Jul 31 13:25 ExtensionWebSocketCreationStatus.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff   538 Jul 31 13:25 ExtensionWebSocketMessageHandler.class

./pantherkitty:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  4 jeff  staff  128 Sep  3 22:01 burp

./pantherkitty/burp:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  4 jeff  staff  128 Sep  3 18:14 sessionsender

./pantherkitty/burp/sessionsender:
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1738 Sep  3 18:14 Sender.class
-rw-r--r--  1 jeff  staff  1739 Sep  3 18:14 SessionSender.class


I don't know the Burp API, but usually the plugin API doesn't have to be included into the plugin, it is already present in the main program. Therefore implementation 'net.portswigger.burp.extensions:montoya-api:+' doesn't seem correct to me. I would change it from implementation to compile . Without that dependency you also shouldn't need the shadow plugin.
